# Use of the idx parameter of match function with a regexp of the form "^....." | Julia 0.6

Tags: regex, julia, pcre

I am not really sure if I am asking a real question here.
But, it is possible to use the the `idx` parameter of the function `match` to search at the beginning of the string?. Because it's not working for me and maybe it's supposed to work that way.

```
julia> str= "    # a comment"
julia> str[5:end]
"# a comment"
julia> match(r"^#", str,5)

julia> match(r"^#", str[5:end])
RegexMatch("#")
```

Comment: Yes it looks as if you can't say both `^` to mean start of line _and_ start at index 5 at the same time...

Comment: I suppose you are right. I always thought that the ANCHORED option in PCRE only added the ^ at the beginning of the pattern.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To match at the beginning of the string the anchored option has to be setted.

```
julia> str= "    # a comment"
julia> reg  = r"#"
julia> reg.match_options = reg.match_options | Base.PCRE.ANCHORED
julia> match(reg, str,4)

julia> match(reg, str,5)
RegexMatch("#")
```